# How do youtube read favicons?

Tags: favicon, youtube-channels

How does Youtube read the favicons to the channel?

I've linked my my favicons like this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

but it doesnt show right on my channel, and it seems to read the .ico file from the right place

```
<img src="//s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?feature=youtube_channel&amp;domain=www.MY_PAGE.dk" class="favicon" alt="">
```

Thanks for your help! 
- Chris

Comment: Try to remove the / in the href:
href="favicon.ico"

Comment: i've tried that aswell, with no success.